# Why is appering a pagination error after click in the search button?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page "`https://proj.test/user/profile?user=2#myRegistrations`" where I have two tabs, one tab show the past registrations of a user in conferences and other tab the next registrations of the user in a conference. The user can click "Past Registrations" to check the past registrations and click in "Next Registrations" to check his next registrations in conferences. And its working.

In this same page, above the tabs, I have a form for the user to search for a conference name where he his registered. But when the user enters some text in the form search input like "test" and click in "Search" it appears "`Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$participants (View: /Users/john/projects/proj/resources/views/users/index.blade.php)`". Do you know what can be the issue?

Code in he view:

```
<div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myTickets" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

        <form method="get" class="clearfix  w-75" method="POST" action="{{ route('user.searchRegistration') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group col col-md-6 px-0">
                <div class="input-group" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Search Registrations"
                           name="search_registration"
                           value="{{old('search_registration')}}"/>
                    <button class="input-group-addon">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="{{route('user.cleanSearchRegistration')}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary"
           id="cleanSearchRegistration">Clean Search</a>
    </div>

    @if(session('searchedRegistrations'))
        @if(session('searchedRegistrations')->count() != null)
            @foreach(session('searchedRegistrations') as $registration)
                @foreach(session('searchedRegistrations')->participants as $participant)
                    @if(!empty($registration))
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <h5>{{optional($registration->conference)->name}}</h5>

                            @if ($registration->status == 'C')
                                <a href="{{route('conference.registrationInfo',
                                    ['id' => $registration->conference->id,
                                    'slug' => $registration->conference->slug,
                                    'regID'=> $registration->id])}}"
                                   class="btn btn-primary ml-2"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Registration document
                                </a>
                            @endif
                            @if ($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')
                                <a href="{{route('conferences.certificateInfo',
                                    [
                                    'regID'=> $registration->id])}}"
                                   class="btn btn-primary ml-2"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download certificate
                                </a>
                                @break
                            @endif
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
            <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                {{session('searchedRegistrations')->fragment('searchRegistrations')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
            </div>
        @else
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <i class="material-icons">info</i>
                <span>Your search didnt return any result.</span>
            </div>
        @endif
    @else
        <div class="d-flex mb-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active border" href="#nextConferences" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Next
                        Conferences</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link border" href="#PastRegistrations" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Past
                        Conferences</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="nextConferences" role="tabpanel"
                 aria-labelledby="home-tab">

                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
                        @foreach($nextRegistration->participants as $participant)
                            @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference) || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->start_date))
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->name}}</h5>

                                    @if ($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')
                                        <a href="{{route('conferences.certificateInfo',
                                    [
                                    'regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"
                                           class="btn btn-primary ml-2"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download Certificate</a>
                                        @break
                                    @endif

                                    @if ($nextRegistration->status == 'C')
                                        <a href="{{route('conferences.registrationInfo',
                                    [
                                    'regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"
                                           class="btn btn-primary ml-2"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Registration document
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    {{$nextRegistrations->fragment('nextConferences')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade show clearfix" id="pastConferences" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($pastRegistrations as $pastRegistration)
                        @foreach($pastRegistration->participants as $participant)
                            @if(!empty($pastRegistration->conference) || !empty($pastRegistration->conference->start_date))
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <h5>{{optional($pastRegistration->conference)->name}}</h5>
                                    @if ($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')
                                        <a href="{{route('conferences.certificateInfo',['regID'=> $pastRegistration->id])}}"
                                           class="btn btn-primary ml-2"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download Certificate
                                        </a>
                                        @break
                                    @endif
                                    @if ($pastRegistration->status == 'C')
                                        <a href="{{route('conferences.registrationInfo',
                                    [
                                    'regID'=> $pastRegistration->id])}}"
                                           class="btn btn-primary ml-2"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Registration info
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    {{$pastRegistrations->fragment('pastConferences')->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `session('searchedRegistrations')` is the Pagination instance. There is no property named `participants` nor would there be any random properties (it is a container, not what it contains). I would imagine a model instance contained in the collection might have a `participants` property though.

```
@foreach(session('searchedRegistrations') as $registration)
    @foreach(session('searchedRegistrations')->participants as $participant)
```

I am guessing that should be

```
    @foreach($registration->participants as $participant)
```